# sudo command after long sleep call without re-prompting sudo password

Tags: bash, sudo, bashrc

I'm trying to write a simple bash function that sleeps X-number of mins and then runs a system sleep command (for me it's `sudo pm-suspend` since I'm on Ubuntu) right now the function looks like this:

```
function sleepin {
  sleep $(bc <<< $1*60); sudo pm-suspend
}
```

The first argument is after how many mins the sleep is supposed to happen. The problem is that after the sleep the script prompts me for the sudo password.

#### How should I re-write the script so that it doesn't prompt me for the sudo password after the sleep?

(I've tried to call `sudo sleepin 30` but it still prompts me for the password. Note that if the sleep call is small enough bash doesn't prompts for password, but for a longer sleep it will..)

Comment: Why don't you simply authorize that command without a password in sudo's config?

Comment: If you do go down the NOPASSWD route, you may want to use `sleep $(bc <<< $1*60) && sudo pm-suspend` instead, so that if you Ctrl-C the function it wont run pm-suspend (and you can cancel it from suspending your OS).

Comment: Have you looked into modifying the `timestamp_timeout` default value in sudoers? You should be able to alter the timeout on a per-user basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Mat suggested, you can allow the user to run pm-suspend without a password.

Run `sudo visudo`

Add `youruser ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /path/to/pm-suspend`

Answer (score 7):

Put the sleep inside the sudo command.

```
seconds=$(($1 * 60))
sudo sh -c "sleep $seconds; pm-suspend"
```

Answer (score 3):

Going on a tangent: is there any particular reason you don't want to use the at daemon?

```
echo 'pm-suspend' | sudo at now + 15 minutes
```

might be a starting point.